# QR Factorization for Linear Regression Line in R (using qr.solve)

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

So I'm trying to figure out how to use the command `qr.solve` in R to solve for the components of a best fit line (slope and intercept) in accordance to a particular data set. Although I already know how to do this using the `lm` function, to my understanding, the qr factorization of a matrix could yield the same thing. Would someone be able to explain how such a thing is true, and maybe its benefits over a simple linear model command? Could the inputs of the `qr.solve` function be implements in R, or would I have to solve it myself first and plug it into R afterwards?

I tried inputting my data set (2 columns each of whose rows represent points on a graph) into a matrix and using that as an x argument in the function `qr.solve`. However, I'm not too sure what to plug in for b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR decomposition can solve Ax = b. Thus when the least squares solution gets to the point: XTy = XTXB we can use A = XTX and b = XTy to solve for x = B.

```
?qr.solve

mtcars
lm(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)
with(mtcars, {
  X <<- cbind(1, cyl)
  y <- mpg
  A = t(X) %*% X
  b = t(X) %*% y
  qr.solve(A, b)
})
```

Comment: Beautiful. This makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: On second thought, why did you utilize the <<- when defining the matrix X? I just read up on it, and nothing really shouts why this would have been preferred over simply using <-. Any insight?

Comment: @Alex03 no reason, I was trying to see what X was but it wouldn't store it after running the 'with' command if I didn't use the global <<-

Comment: Ah okay perfect haha. Just making sure I didn't miss some logical reasoning behind it

Answer (score 1):

Just elaborating a little more,

Linear regression aims to solve the least squares problem with the normal equation:

`β = inv(X'X)(X'y) = solve(X'X, X'y)`

Here, `X` represents the matrix with the independent predictor variables and `y` is the dependent response variable, `β` being the coefficients to be estimated. Also, `X'` denotes the transpose of matrix `X`.

With `QR` decomposition, `X` is decomposed into an orthonormal matrix `Q` and an upper triangular matrix `R` as follows:

`X = QR`, so that `Q'Q = I`

Then `β` can be estimated as shown below:

`β = inv(X'X)(X'y) = inv(R'Q'QR)(R'Q'y) = inv(R'R)(R'Q'y) = inv(R)inv(R')(R')(Q'y)`

i.e.,

`β = inv(R)(Q'y) = solve(R, Q'y)`

Above shows how `QR` decomposition makes linear regression much cheaper, since `R` is an upper-triangular matrix, the linear system can be solved much more efficiently.

Now, let's compare the performances of different approaches to solve the linear system. with some randomly generated data:

```
m <- 100 # number of data points
n <- 6   # number of predictor variables
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(rnorm(m*n), nrow=m)
beta <- matrix(sample(1:(n+1),n+1), ncol=1)
y <- X1%*% beta + rnorm(m)
X1 <- cbind(rep(1,m), X) # add intercept term
```

First let's confirm that all the following methods produces the same output (the same coefficients are estimated):

```
lm(y~X)$coeff   
# (Intercept)          X1          X2          X3          X4          X5          X6 
#   6.5233774  -0.2827844   0.3469484  -0.9083762   0.4903771  -0.3217761  -0.0326980 

as.numeric(solve(t(X1)%*%X1, t(X1)%*%y))
# [1]  6.5233774 -0.2827844  0.3469484 -0.9083762  0.4903771 -0.3217761 -0.0326980

q <- qr(X1)
as.numeric(solve(qr.R(q), t(qr.Q(q))%*%y))
# [1]  6.5233774 -0.2827844  0.3469484 -0.9083762  0.4903771 -0.3217761 -0.0326980

as.numeric(qr.solve(X1, y))
# [1]  6.5233774 -0.2827844  0.3469484 -0.9083762  0.4903771 -0.3217761 -0.0326980
```

As expected, we obtained the exact same value of the coefficients in the above approoaches.

Now, let's compare runtime for solving the linear system with normal equation and using `QR` decomposition (assuming that `Q` and `R` already precomputed).

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
q <- qr(X1)
Q <- qr.Q(q)
R <- qr.R(q)
autoplot(
  microbenchmark(solve(t(X1)%*%X1, t(X1)%*%y),
                 solve(R, t(Q)%*%y), times=1000L)
)
```

As expected again, the solution can be obtained much faster with matrices obtained from `QR` decomposition.

[image]